# What's wrong with this fast refreshable view definition: it is not complex and complete, however ORA-12015 is raised

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views

What's wrong with this fast refreshable view definition in Oracle 10.2:

```
create table A
(
  ID number(19,0) not null constraint A_PK primary key using index
, C number(9,0) not null
);

create table B
(
  ID number(19,0) not null constraint B_PK primary key using index
, A_ID number(19,0) not null constraint A_FK references A(ID) on delete cascade
, D number(9,0) not null
);

create index B_FK_IDX on B(A_ID);

create materialized view log on A 
  with primary key, rowid, sequence (C) including new values;
create materialized view log on B
  with primary key, rowid, sequence (A_ID, D) including new values;

 create materialized
   view X
        refresh fast with primary key
     as
 select A.ID as A_ID
      , A.ROWID as A_ROWID
      , B.ID as B_ID
      , B.ROWID as B_ROWID
      , A.C
      , B.D
   from A
  inner join
        B
          on B.A_ID = A.ID;
```

When the script is executed I get:

```
table A created.
table B created.
index B_FK_IDX created.
materialized view LOG created.
materialized view LOG created.
...[view definition and local error message left out]
SQL-Error: ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
12015. 00000 -  "cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query"
*Cause:    Neither ROWIDs and nor primary key constraints are supported for
           complex queries.
*Action:   Reissue the command with the REFRESH FORCE or REFRESH COMPLETE
           option or create a simple materialized view.
```

I can not see a violation of any of the restrictions for materialized views as defined in Oracle's support document 179466.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must not use ANSI join syntax, use the old Oracle join syntax. It is a bug in Oracle.
Long time ago I opened a case for this, however Oracle considers this only as lack of documentation!

Comment: wow, join worked with two tables for me in Oracle 12c R1, but not with 3 tables, old one worked well...

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm):

> *Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Joins Only*
>
> Defining queries for materialized views with joins only and no aggregates have the following restrictions on fast refresh:
>
> All restrictions from "General Restrictions on Fast Refresh".
>
> They cannot have GROUP BY clauses or aggregates.
>
> **Rowids of all the tables in the FROM list must appear in the SELECT list of the query.**
>
> Materialized view logs must exist with rowids for all the base tables in the FROM list of the query.

Comment: @David_Aldridge I added the rowids (thanks). However, the error still occurs.

Comment: @Claude Hmmm try specifying REFRESH FORCE, and then use DBMS_MView.Explain_View to get its capabilities in terms of fast refresh: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm#i1008271 It may be that it's eligible for fast refresh in your required circumstances but not all circumstances.

Comment: @David_Aldridge the ANSI JOIN was the problem - see Wernfried's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33959242/2107731 Thanks anyway